# Ldap Integration module

Tags: drupal

HI,

I have given the server name, base dn, and the other reguired fields in /admin/settings/ldap/ldapauth/add and in advance configuration i have tested and it shows ldap authentication sucessfull. After this when i logout and enter the ldap username and password i am not able to login to the admin section.
I am not knowing whether i am doing any mistake in configuration or whats wrong why i am not able to authenticate the ldap users and login to the site.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the support queue for the module?